# Recursive Integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $\int _o^1 e^x(x-1)^ndx=16-6e$ find the value of n (n is a positive integer $n\le5$).

ATTEMPT:

Let $I=\int _o^1 e^x(x-1)^ndx$

By using $\int _a^b f(x)dx=\int _a^b f(a+b-x)dx$

$I=\int _o^1 e^{1-x}(-x)^ndx$

$I=(-1)^n\int _o^1 e^{1-x}(x)^ndx$

But integration of either of these two is in terms of **Gamma function** which i haven't studied yet.

I tried doing algebraic manipulation like adding the two integrals but couldn't come up with a  concrete idea.

Can we solve this problem without getting into the complexity of the integral, just by using properties of definite integration?

Comment: Try using integration by parts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrating by parts gives
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 e^x(x-1)^n\,dx&=
\Bigl[e^x(x-1)^n\Bigr]_0^1-\int_0^1ne^x(x-1)^{n-1}\,dx\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}-n\int_0^1e^x(x-1)^{n-1}\,dx
\end{align}
So, if we set
$$
a_n=\int_0^1 e^x(x-1)^n\,dx
$$
we have the recursion
$$
a_n=(-1)^{n+1}-na_{n-1}
$$
with
$$
a_0=\int_0^1e^x=e-1
$$

Comment: I totally agree with your answer ... but I have a problem since your answer gives $a_1=-1-(e-1)=-e$ while it should be $2-e$. Then, $16-6e$ cannot be found in the sequence while it should correspond to $n=3$ (I think). Where is the problem ? I am stuck.

Comment: I found !! $a_n=-(-1)^n-na_{n-1}$. Crazy, isn't it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, I forgot a $-1$, thanks for noting.